# Is Fiona a parody of Ladyhawke?

Tags: character, analysis, shrek, ladyhawke

A couple days ago I was watching again [Ladyhawke](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0089457) (1985) and when briefly explaining the plot to my young sister, even though she wasn't paying much attention because of Facebook (kids these days...), she quickly associated Isabeau "Ladyhawke" (Michelle Pfeiffer) with Princess Fiona, from Shrek.

I confess I never considered that and I also didn't find anything about the matter, only that "Shrek" is based on an existing book.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Maybe**

I can't find any official word on it, but the idea the *Shrek* borrowed heavily from the plot of *Ladyhawke* is not uncommon.

e.g.: From [this review](http://threemenonablog.blogspot.co.nz/2011/11/film-review-ladyhawke-1985.html):

> At least when *Shrek* half-inched the plot, it was consistent throughout.

(Half-inched: British slang; pinched, or stolen)

IMDB also includes *Shrek* under the "Spoofed in" connection section for [*Ladyhawke*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089457/movieconnections).

And in the book [100 Animated Feature Films](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=LWodBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA185&lpg=PA185&dq=ladyhawke+vs+shrek&source=bl&ots=xVy6UFjApr&sig=IHMPSZdKbHL4nwG826aqkj5mbfM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVi93ymsjUAhWDtpQKHYm0CcwQ6AEIUzAL#v=onepage&q=ladyhawke%20vs%20shrek&f=false) by Andrew Osmond also draws a link between the two, saying:

> ... the loose later scenes become a star-crossed, shape-changing romance, echoing the live-action *Ladyhawke* (1985), and, more overtly, Disney's *Beauty and the Beast*.

While there appears to be popular opinion that *Shrek* at least referenced *Ladyhawke*, I'm unable to find any official word about whether Fiona was an intentional parody.

Finally, the book on which Shrek is based is called [Shrek!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrek!), and was written in 1990, five years after *Ladyhawke*.  Again, there's no indication that the book deliberately parodies *Ladyhawke*.

Comment: I knew it! (slam the table) XD